# Angular 2 html directives and attribute directives

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm new to Angular 2.

Can someone please explain the difference between the `html directives and attribute directives`? Why are they both needed?

**Example:**

`<rating [rate]="rate" (rate-change)="onUpdate($event)"></rating>`

So:

`rating` is what i call "html directive" but I'm not sure what it's for?

`[rate]` is an attribute directive that sets component property named "rate".

`(rate-change)` is an attribute directive that calls a component method called `rateChange`.

Any other types of `directives`?

Comment: i meant to the difference between `html directives and attribute directives`

Answer (score 1):

html directives are for managing dom elements like creating elements. attribute directives modify properties of elements. so angular could create several divs, then later change a div's text.

Comment: in the example above? why is there `<rating>` what is this translated to?